# How to use two keyboards simultaneously on a single computer w/windows?

Tags: keyboard, productivity, office-live

I am working with a colleague on the same computer, but I would like the opportunity to work at the same time, I have two USB keyboards and two mouses and use Teamplayer to work with 2 mouses. but for now can only write with one keyboard. Anybody know any program or how to work two keyboards on windows?

Comment: man i have wanted to be able to do this forever

Comment: At a guess we've a pair of wet-behind-the-ears developers forced to pair program. They want to increase their efficency by both working on different things at the same time . . . you'd think code shops would get this and give ever developer their own machine and DOUBLE THEIR PRODUCTIVITY. Man, I think we're on to something here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2008/11/22/install-multiple-mouse-and-keyboard-on-one-computer/ on how to do what you are wanting.