# How do I simultaneously use two keyboards?

Tags: keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use two keyboards simultaneously on a single computer w/windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/78350/how-to-use-two-keyboards-simultaneously-on-a-single-computer-w-windows)

I prefer to type with one keyboard per hand. In my last job, I had a setup that worked using a macbook pro and the apple external keyboard plugged into a big apple monitor which then plugged into a special non-usb port on the macbook. Now I'm using a regular monitor and keyboard, but I can't use shift across the keyboards.

For example, I want to type a capital A. I hold down the shift key on one keyboard, and i press the 'a' key on the other. The result is a lower case a. It was by far the most comfortable typing I've ever done and I want to figure out how to continue to do it.

Comment: This question seems to have been unfairly closed, as it was about OSX and the "duplicate" is about windows.  For future reference, [DualKeyboard](https://github.com/pnc/dual-keyboards) filled this purpose on OSX, but has been superceded by [my-multiple-keyboards](https://github.com/mejedi/my-multiple-keyboards), and now [Karabiner](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner).

Answer (score 3):

Simply connecting two keyboards should do it. On my notebook, I got a secondary usb keyboard connected - just tried and pressed 'shift' on the built-in keyboard and another literal on the usb keyboard - seems to work exactly as you described. 
What does not work across keyboards is state changing keys - for example, pressing CapsLock on one keyboard will only affect that keyboard (this might vary by OS tho).

Comment: I have a similar settup to O G (with a Lenovo notebook running Win 7 Ultimate in a docking station and a separate 22" screen, USB keyboard and mouse) and both shift and caps lock work across keyboards, so it would seem that whether a two keyboard setup works exactly as needed depends on various things.

Comment: I did eventually find a solution. The problem is that OS X associates each keyboard with a particular device id and as you type on each keyboard, so that the modifier key is only associated with the device it originates on. Download the program and view the discussion here:

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?p=9421743